# Is this Database Design for Common Wealth Australian Games fine or need some adjustments?

Tags: sql, database, erd

[image]

This is the image of the ERD, I need some suggestions about it.

I've been working on it for quite a while, a guy gave a negative review about it so I'm confused whether the design based on the scenario provided is acceptable or there are error in it.

Tables are described in the ERD

Comment: I am no expert on the commonwealth games but I am pretty sure there are more competitions than swimming and as far as swimming goes this design seems to be all over the place so it’s kind of hard to understand what this design is supposed to handle.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah so this design is focused on Swimmers only.